# How to catch a failsafe exception in rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

In my rails app, when ever the mysql service is stopped. I see a

> /!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Tue Dec 28 14:37:59
>   +0530 2010   Status: 500 Internal Server Error   Mysql::Error

I could not catch this exception in my rescue_action_in_public exception handler to give a custom error msg. Is there anyway to catch this exception?

Answer (score 0):

This link appears to explain what you ask.  I can't speak to it's applicability in your particular situation, however.

http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/11/re-raise-a-ruby-exception-in-a-rails-rescue_from-statement/